# Template function in argument of Expect call function in Hippomock

Tags: c++, hippomocks

I want to isolate `writeMemory` but i can't because of the following error:

> ../../Util/UnitTest++/../../UnitTests/KeeperDive_Test.h:66:57: error: expected expression mocks.ExpectCall(Skillmock, Skill::writeMemory).With(template (Skillmock));

```
class Skill
{
protected:
    template <class T> void writeMemory(const char *key, T value)
    {
        PY_ERROR_TRY
        {
            skillMemory[key] = (T)value;
        }
        PY_ERROR_CATCH
    }
};

TEST(run)
{    
    MockRepository mocks;
    Skill *Skillmock = mocks.Mock<Skill>();
    mocks.ExpectCall(Skillmock, Skill::writeMemory).With(template<class T>(Skillmock));
}
```

Comment: Why the stray `template<class T>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect a call on a template method - only on a specific instance of the method. For this case you'll also not be able to mock a non-virtual class member, in part because that's not implemented but mostly because this instance would be fully inlined anyway, and cannot be mocked out afterwards.